# Can't verify successful twitter follow

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, api, twitter

I have a script that suppose to verify if a user has followed another on twitter. This is after a window pops up from a button click on my website prompting the user to follow the other user on their twitter page.

After they do that they are suppose to click confirm on my website. My code then checks if the user did this and either confirm success or bring up an error.

I've tested this and no matter how many times I follow a twitter user it always brings up the error that I didn't. I figure it has something to do with this part of javascript code.

```
   function followuser(str,user,name)
    {
    document.getElementById("Hint").style.display='block';
        $("#Hint").html('Verifiziere@'+name+'...');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "plugins/tw/complete.php",
            data: "me="+str+"&him="+user,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#Hint").html(msg);
                var coins = $("#coins").html().replace(" Coins", "");
                coins = parseInt(coins) + parseInt($("#" + user + "points").html().replace("Coins: <b>","").replace("</b>",""));
                $("#coins").html(coins + " Coins");
                removeElement('boxes', user);
            }
        });
    }
```

In complete.php file

```
$url  = "http://api.twitter.com/1/friendships/exists.json?screen_name_a=" . $data3->twitter . "&screen_name_b=".$id;
        $page = get_data($url);
        $json_a = json_decode($page,true);
```

In an if statement $page always comes up false.

Comment: Someone gets "coins" if and only if they follow you.  Seems legit!  (Have you tried debugging the value of `$url` and then visiting it using a browser?  If you have, and that part returns you the correct response, then I would be suspicious of your get_data function.)

Comment: Seems like I have to Update the REST API v1 to v1.1. How I would go about doing this with my could I have no idea.